# Suppress layout animation on one child view

Tags: android

I'm setting layout animation to list view (my items are dropping down). In list view I have a header that I don’t what to animate.

How can I suppress animation on my header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this with the help of this Google Group discussion.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/F7_zE_k9KO8

I end up creating a custom view and overriding getAnimation() witch returned null.

```
public class HeaderSearchNoAnimationVIew extends LinearLayout {
public HeaderSearchNoAnimationVIew(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LayoutInflater i = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    i.inflate(R.layout.list_header_search, this);
}
@Override
public Animation getAnimation() {
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a static view present at all times, have you considered using a separate view not part of the list view for your header?

Comment: Unfortunately the header view have to scroll along with the rest of list.